# Possible formula for $\sum_{} (\alpha\beta)^2$ and $\sum_{} \alpha\beta(\alpha+\beta)$

Tags: polynomials, summation, roots, quartics

Given a quartic equation in the form $$ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e=0$$ and its roos $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ and $\delta$, can anyone please help me find a formula for $$\sum_{} (\alpha\beta)^2 \quad \text{and} \quad \sum_{} 
\alpha\beta(\alpha+\beta)\;?$$

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: @Rahdin Zaman I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I was able to derive a formula for a cubic equation by squaring  $\sum_{}  \alpha\beta$ but this method did not work for quartics. Should I post a picture of my attempt?

Comment: @Rahdin Zaman Yes, of course! It's better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Since we have a quartic equation, we see that $a\neq0.$

Thus, the Viete's theorem we obtain: $$\frac{1}{4}\sum_{sym}\alpha^2\beta^2=\left(\frac{1}{4}\sum_{sym}\alpha\beta\right)^2-2\sum_{cyc}\alpha\sum_{cyc}\alpha\beta\gamma+\prod_{cyc}\alpha=$$
$$=\left(\frac{c}{a}\right)^2-2\left(-\frac{b}{a}\right)\left(-\frac{d}{a}\right)+2\cdot\frac{e}{a}=\frac{c^2-2bd+2ae}{a^2}.$$
$$\sum_{cyc}\alpha^2(\beta+\gamma+\delta)=\sum_{cyc}\alpha\cdot\frac{1}{4}\sum_{sym}\alpha\beta-3\sum_{cyc}\alpha\beta\gamma=$$
$$=-\frac{b}{a}\cdot\frac{c}{a}-3\left(-\frac{d}{a}\right)=\frac{3ad-bc}{a^2}.$$

PS. $$\sum_{sym}\alpha\beta=4(\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma+\alpha\delta+\beta\gamma+\beta\delta+\gamma\delta).$$
$$\sum_{cyc}\alpha^2(\beta+\gamma+\delta)=\alpha^2(\beta+\gamma+\delta)+\beta^2(\gamma+\delta+\alpha)+\gamma^2(\delta+\alpha+\beta)+\delta^2(\alpha+\beta+\gamma).$$
By the way, $$\sum_{sym}\alpha^2\beta=2\left(\alpha^2(\beta+\gamma+\delta)+\beta^2(\gamma+\delta+\alpha)+\gamma^2(\delta+\alpha+\beta)+\delta^2(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)\right).$$

Comment: what does $sym$ and $cyc$ mean in this context?

Comment: @crystal_math I added something. See now.